# How to defeat proxy abuse with nginx?

Tags: nginx, proxy, centos7

i noticed that my website seo going down, after i accessed my google webmaster console i found some Russian domains mirroring my website with proxy , the first thing i did is try to block the ip but they are to many and they changes constantly , this is some access in my nginx log

```
141.101.77.80 - - [19/Apr/2018:03:42:56 +0200] "GET /fuck14 HTTP/1.1" 404 107 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
5.8.47.164 - - [19/Apr/2018:03:45:45 +0200] "GET /fuck14 HTTP/1.1" 404 107 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
95.181.218.167 - - [19/Apr/2018:03:46:05 +0200] "GET /fuck14 HTTP/1.1" 404 102 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
95.181.177.39 - - [19/Apr/2018:03:46:17 +0200] "GET /fuck14 HTTP/1.1" 404 107 "" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; Win64; x64; rv:56.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/56.0"
```

So my question is , is there any way to block proxy requests ?

Answer (score 0):

You could use getipintel API calls inside your site-code. Take a look at http://getipintel.net/

Furthermore you can just parse your access log and try to make a list of proxied ip's. Just a quick google lookup and you see that 5.8.47.164 is only provided publically at some paid proxie sites. You can get a hold of public proxy sites and just use that list as a blacklist (this can be done with nginx or iptables).

In the end you want to automate the proxy-list scraping or go with the getipintel.